# Invoking a method on Space bar or Enter Press + MAC APP

Tags: objective-c

I am developing a mac standalone app.

I want to let user press enter on search button to get result from DB.

Is there any way we can give control to search when user presses 'Enter Key'. 
It works great on 'Space Bar'.

How can it be possible on 'Enter Key' in objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set your button's "key equivalent" to the return key. To do that, select your button in the Interface Builder, open the inspector, and look for the entry labeled "key equivalent". Click it, and hit the return key. That's it!

But if you have a search box already, it's usually a better idea to do away with the search button. For example, Safari's Google search field doesn't have a "Google Search" button. Instead, hitting the return key at the end of the search phrase automatically triggers the search. If you want to do that, you just need to set the target and the action for the search box.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yuji.. I got it... I have been in iPhone development and just shifted to Mac apps.

Comment: I found bit issue when i have two buttons on view and with two distinct actions. When i apply enter key on both buttons only first button action is invoked on both.

Comment: The key equivalent needs to be unique within a view, unfortunately. Otherwise there's no telling which ui control is activated.